# How to remove overlays from PDF file using PDFBox?

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika 1.17 to extract content from PDF files. There is a small image overlay on a page in PDF due to which Tika is not able extract any content from that page but for rest of the pages it is working fine.
Is there any way to remove overlay from PDF page using PDFBox before sending it to Tika?

As a workaround, I converted the PDF to PNG and Tika is using TesseractOCR to extract content. But I am losing some content and text format this way.

Comment: please share the pdf in question or describe technically how that *image overlay* is built.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the pdf. It looks like a signature image that is overlayed on pdf page. Adobe acrobat reader is not showing anything but on my mac, when I click on it, it is getting selected. I am able to copy and paste it on to word doc. Thanks.